# Spring Boot HttpSecurity - @PreAuthorize - How to set AuthenticationFilter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am currently developing a API Authorization. So basically I have a filter `JwtAuthorizationFilter`. And in my RestController I want to annotate the request that should be filtered via `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")` for example. So my question is now: How do i have to setup the `WebSecurityConfigureAdapter` (or any other thing) to link the annotations with the JwtAuthorizationFilter?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // Basically permit every request, but if needed (through @PreAuthorize) check via JwtAuthorizationFilter)
    }
}
```

Thank you!
Best regards Sebastian

Comment: why do you have a jwt filter when there is already one built in into spring security? https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-architecture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of `JwtAuthorizationFilter` should be to set the `Authentication`'s granted authorities. Then, Spring Security's default method security will suffice.

You have a couple of options:

#### Use Spring Security's built-in JWT support

If the JWT is minted by an authorization server, then [Spring Security's default JWT support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.0-M1/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver) may suffice. Spring Security ships with `BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter` and `JwtAuthenticationProvider`. The filter will parse the `Authorization` header to get the token and the provider will validate the token and construct an `Authentication` that's based on the `scope` or `scp` claim. In that case, you'd do something like `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('SCOPE_ADMIN')")`.

If you need to customize how to convert JWT claims into `GrantedAuthority`s, then you can publish a `JwtAuthenticationConverter` `@Bean`.

For complete setup details, take a look at [Spring Security's OAuth 2.0 Resource Server sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/master/servlet/spring-boot/java/oauth2/resource-server/hello-security). Basically, though, your configuration would look like this:

```java
http
    .authorizeRequests((authz) -> authz
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
    )
    .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2
        .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults())
    );
```

#### Use Spring Security's Built-in JWT support without an Authorization Server

Spring Security's existing support is designed with an authorization server in mind, but this isn't a requirement.

You can instead have your application [mint self-signed tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64578081/spring-security-filters-for-jwt-based-authentication-verification-and-authoriza/64669582#64669582).

#### Roll Your Own

You could keep your `JwtAuthorizationFilter`, but it's not clear why Spring Security's existing support is insufficient. To add a filter, you can simply do `addFilterBefore(myFilter, BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.class)`. You can take a look at [`BearerTokenAuthenicationFilter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/5.5.0-M1/oauth2/oauth2-resource-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/resource/web/BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.java) as an example of some of the things you should consider when creating your own filter.

Comment: Thank you for this extensive clarification!

Comment: My pleasure, @SebastianBrunnert